# LightBox Plugin that Supports Forms

Tags: plugins, spring-mvc, lightbox

I am developing a Spring MVC application and i am looking for a Lightbox plugin that supports forms, meaning i can call my form in it and it will be displayed just like a picture does. Has anyone ever done this before please advise.

I would also like to know if there is any specific call to the light box when using an MVC design pattern or will a simple call to the forms url will work.

Comment: I guess this question is not relevant anymore since you got already working your form with fancybox, didn't you?

Comment: yes man but thanks so much for your effort in helping and guiding me